# role management on a certain discord id

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is what i have but it still doesn't work

```
@client.command()
async def addrole(ctx, member : discord.Member, role : discord.Role):
  if ctx.guild.id == "777563438469087244":
    await member.add_roles("799957984062865448")
  else:
    return
```

I want to give anyone that joins the member role but JUST in that server id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ctx.guild.id` returns an integer type data. In your code, you tried to compare it with a string. You just have to delete the quotes. Then, you cannot add role with the role's id. You have to add the role's itself.

```py
@client.command()
async def addrole(ctx, member : discord.Member, role : discord.Role):
  if ctx.guild.id == 777563438469087244:
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: How do i make that an event on member join?

Answer (score 0):

1. `Guild.id` is an integer, you're comparing it to a string
2. in `Member.add_roles` you need a role object, not a string

```py
if ctx.guild.id == 777563438469087244:
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

Also this is a command, not an event, if you want to add roles when someone joins the guild you should use the `on_member_join` event. Also you need to enable `intents.members`